# How to specify the position in txt file to delete record in C programming

Tags: c, file, record

```
void deleteRecord()
{
FILE *fp, *fdel;
struct person obj;
char number[20];

printf("\n============================");
printf("\n            DELETE");
printf("\n============================\n\n");
fflush(stdin);
printf("Enter student number to delete  :");
scanf("%s", number);
fp=fopen("D:\\data.txt","r");
fdel=fopen("D:\\del.txt","w");
while(fscanf(fp,"\n%s\n%s %s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n",
             obj.stdNumb, obj.firstName, obj.lastName, obj.icPass,
             obj.nationality, obj.gender, obj.dateOfBirth,
             obj.contact, obj.address)==1)
    if(stricmp(number, obj.stdNumb)!=0)
        fprintf(fdel, "\n%s\n%s %s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n",
                obj.stdNumb, obj.firstName, obj.lastName, obj.icPass,
                obj.nationality, obj.gender, obj.dateOfBirth, obj.contact,
                obj.address);
fclose(fp);
fclose(fdel);
remove("D:\\data.txt");
rename("D:\\del.txt","D:\\data.txt");
printf("Successully Deleted.");
getch();
}
```

here is my full code, I removed the `;` after while, and I removed `fgetc`, if I run and delete record, it will delete all record.. it's still not specified.. how to fix this?

Comment: I've edited your code formatting to break up the long lines into multiple lines. This simplifies finding a crucial and serious error in your code as no horizontal scrolling is needed. Making code easy to read is very important, not only for our sake but for your own.

Comment: I've removed the code irrelevant to the problem, and reformatted the rest to make the structure of your `deleteRecord` function more obvious. Why are you comparing `fscanf( ... ) == 1`? Check [the documentation for fscanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fscanf/#return).

Answer (score 2):

At first view, your "while" ends with a ";", which causes it to execute nothing, except the "while" itself.

All the things you do in your intended loop are executed ALWAYS, after the evaluation of the "while" command!

By the way, it seems to be that closing the files inside the loop will cause problems on the second execution of the loop.

Comment: +1 for noticing the semicolon at the end of the `while`. For the OP, keep lines short, break them up into multiple lines if possible, because it makes the code _much_ easier to read.

Comment: +1 for the tip on code style. This type of tip must be teached to the newbies.

Comment: guys, thanks for tips :p.. i edited some codes, but it even deletes all record.. any suggestion? so so newbieeee @NiloPaim

Answer (score 1):

After the last edit, the error in your code has changed completely, now it's how you check the condition in the loop:

```
while (fscanf(...) == 1)
```

The `scanf` family of function returns either `EOF` on error or end-of-file, or the number of successfully scanned conversions it made.

Since you have nine conversions, you should check that all nine were made:

```
while (fscanf(...) == 9)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    fclose(fp);
    fclose(fdel);
    remove("D:\\data.txt");
    rename("D:\\del.txt","D:\\data.txt");
```

You may want to move these lines out of `while` loop or at least in the `else` block of preceding `if`.